# If inside if in Firebase Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have this rule to allow only if :

```
!("plan" in request.resource.data.brand.userData)
```

The problem is that sometimes, the request **will not** event have `brand` field, and it will then **deny** the request. It will allow it only if the `brand` field **is there** without `plan`.

How can i first check if `brand` is in `request.resource.data`, *and only if its there*, to check that `plan` is NOT in `userData` ?

Is there `if () if () {}` in Rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for real `if` conditions in Firestore security rules.

There **is** support for [ternary expressions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020) these days however. By combining that with the knowledge that expression evaluation is short circuited (so in `false && expression` and `true || expression` the `expression` will never be evaluated), and you can typically write any condition as a combination of ternaries.

So your combined rules would look something like:

```
allow write: if !("brand" in request.resource.data.keys() && 
                  "plan" in request.resource.data.brand.userData);
```

Comment: Hey Frank, well after MANY experiments this will not work when i update the document, even with an empty object. Once i try to check if "brand" is NOT there, it will fail all the time.

Comment: I am doing an update operation , so, in this case the rule wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok i got it, sorry. on update i should just compare request and resource ! thanks !